# Add Radio buttons as first column in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

I am trying to add new column of radio buttons to my table with the below code. But even though they are getting added the table headers are not moving to the right. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

```
$('tr[data-entity="ess_asset"]').each(function () {
    $(this).children(':first-child').before('<td class="caseCheckbox"><input type="radio" name="caseGroup" /></td>');
```

Comment: Ofc the header is not coming, you will have to add an empty `th` to the `thead` but only once. something like `$('table thead tr').prepend("<th></th>")`

Comment: You could move your filter `[data-entity=...` *inside* the each so that the the loop applies to all rows and adds a `td` to every row (with the checkbox only on the ones you need)